# Circling Text Trail Around Cursor

Tags: javascript, cursor, mouse

I've been searching for a script that creates a cursor text trail moving in a circular motion for quite a while. I feel like such things were everywhere just five years ago on kitschy blog sites.

The only code(s) I've been able to find are authored by Tim Tilton, 
with variations found 
[here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex13/circletext.htm) and [here](http://codepen.io/RG/pen/FvgHh) 
and repeated on a few other sites.

This code seems a bit heavy in that it separates and gives each character of the message it's own div and then use equations to place and move those divs around the cursor.

It's there another way to go about creating such a feature?

A bit of the heavy code here:

```
if (!window.addEventListener && !window.attachEvent || !document.createElement) return;

msg = msg.split('');
var n = msg.length - 1, a = Math.round(size * diameter * 0.208333), currStep = 20,
ymouse = a * circleY + 20, xmouse = a * circleX + 20, y = [], x = [], Y = [], X = [],
o = document.createElement('div'), oi = document.createElement('div'),
b = document.compatMode && document.compatMode != "BackCompat"? document.documentElement : document.body,

mouse = function(e){
 e = e || window.event;
 ymouse = !isNaN(e.pageY)? e.pageY : e.clientY; // y-position
 xmouse = !isNaN(e.pageX)? e.pageX : e.clientX; // x-position
},

makecircle = function(){ // rotation/positioning
 if(init.nopy){
  o.style.top = (b || document.body).scrollTop + 'px';
  o.style.left = (b || document.body).scrollLeft + 'px';
 };
 currStep -= rotation;
 for (var d, i = n; i > -1; --i){ // makes the circle
  d = document.getElementById('iemsg' + i).style;
  d.top = Math.round(y[i] + a * Math.sin((currStep + i) / letter_spacing) * circleY - 15) + 'px';
  d.left = Math.round(x[i] + a * Math.cos((currStep + i) / letter_spacing) * circleX) + 'px';
 };
},

drag = function(){ // makes the resistance
 y[0] = Y[0] += (ymouse - Y[0]) * speed;
 x[0] = X[0] += (xmouse - 20 - X[0]) * speed;
 for (var i = n; i > 0; --i){
  y[i] = Y[i] += (y[i-1] - Y[i]) * speed;
  x[i] = X[i] += (x[i-1] - X[i]) * speed;
 };
 makecircle();
},

init = function(){ // appends message divs, & sets initial values for positioning arrays
 if(!isNaN(window.pageYOffset)){
  ymouse += window.pageYOffset;
  xmouse += window.pageXOffset;
 } else init.nopy = true;
 for (var d, i = n; i > -1; --i){
  d = document.createElement('div'); d.id = 'iemsg' + i;
  d.style.height = d.style.width = a + 'px';
  d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg[i]));
  oi.appendChild(d); y[i] = x[i] = Y[i] = X[i] = 0;
 };
 o.appendChild(oi); document.body.appendChild(o);
 setInterval(drag, 25);
},

ascroll = function(){
 ymouse += window.pageYOffset;
 xmouse += window.pageXOffset;
 window.removeEventListener('scroll', ascroll, false);
};

o.id = 'outerCircleText'; o.style.fontSize = size + 'px';

if (window.addEventListener){
 window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
 document.addEventListener('mouseover', mouse, false);
 document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouse, false);
  if (/Apple/.test(navigator.vendor))
   window.addEventListener('scroll', ascroll, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent){
 window.attachEvent('onload', init);
 document.attachEvent('onmousemove', mouse);
};
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure creating an element for each character is how they all work.

Comment: Do you know of any other examples/options? I'd like to compare the code to what I have, but this code by Tim seems to be the only source I can find anywhere.